# jQuery Mobile MultiPage Not Displaying in Firefox 4

Tags: jquery, mobile, firefox4

Using latest jQuery Mobile 1.1.1, when clicking on a Multipage link #pgDetail, the first page (#pgHome) fades out using opacity 0, but the linked 2nd page (#pgDetail) is still display:none with computed opacity of "1" and doesn't become visible, nothing is displayed, except in firebug of course.

I notice that it's not switching the "ui-page-active" class for the pages, nor the style heights.  If I refresh the browser, the 2nd page displays.  Or if I use firebug to manually move the ui-page-active class from one page to another page, it displays.

I only see this issue on Firefox 4. (Win7).

The same code tests fine and works as expected in Firefox 10, IE 8, Chrome, Safari, etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox 4?? Who would still be using FF4? (I can understand FF3.6, or the current extended support version (FF10, I think?), but FF4 has been unsupported for ages.

Comment: According to the jQuery Mobile Claimed Platform Support:  "Firefox Desktop 4-9 – Tested on OS X 10.7 and Windows 7."  The fact it works fine on IE8 and not FF4 is quite surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today, IE8 worked, but FF didn't. And it finally turned out to be the address. I had it at `........\My Documents\Desktop\HelloWorldWebsite`   This space confused the FF. Then I relocate the html file with another path, no space, and it works on FF.